# user interaction was disabled when using offline storage

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

i have stored my json response in **NSUserdefaults** and i have to show that stored response even the data is in offline the result is ok 
but user interaction for ui is disabled when offline.
hope can any one help

i have tried by giving break points at network reachability is connected or not it is going in to the loop and displaying response but ui interaction is strucked

```
func homePageAPI()
{
       let kUserDefault = UserDefaults.standard

       if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true{
       APIModel().homeApi(withUrl: "", withParameters:"", withComplitionBlock: {(_ responseDict: Dictionary!, _ error:String) -> Void in// here im not displaying my url as it is illegal

           DispatchQueue.main.async (execute:{ () -> Void in
           if (responseDict != nil)
           {
                  kUserDefault.set(responseDict, forKey: "responseDict")
                  self.productresponseArray = (responseDict["server_productresponse"] as AnyObject) as! NSArray
                  self.productDetailsArray = ((responseDict["server_productresponse"] as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "product_dtls") as AnyObject) as! NSArray
                  self.vehicleStatusStringArray = ((responseDict["server_productresponse"] as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "veh_status") as AnyObject) as! NSArray
           }
           })
        })
      }
      else{
            let offlineResponseDict:NSDictionary = kUserDefault.value(forKey: "responseDict") as! NSDictionary
            print(offlineResponseDict as Any)
            self.productresponseArray = (offlineResponseDict["server_productresponse"] as AnyObject) as! NSArray
            self.productDetailsArray = ((offlineResponseDict["server_productresponse"] as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "product_dtls") as AnyObject) as! NSArray
            self.vehicleStatusStringArray = ((offlineResponseDict["server_productresponse"] as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "veh_status") as AnyObject) as! NSArray
      }
      self.homeTableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Comment: self.homeTableView.reloadData() during data reload in table view you do not fore this method to be called again?

Comment: thank u but  i gave button in my custom navigation bar it is also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
func homePageAPI() {
    let kUserDefault = UserDefaults.standard

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        // do something that needs to be run on background thread
        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
            APIModel().homeApi(withUrl: "", withParameters:"", withComplitionBlock: {
                (_ responseDict: Dictionary!, _ error:String) -> Void in// here im not displaying my url as it is illegal
                if (responseDict != nil)
                {
                    kUserDefault.set(responseDict, forKey: "responseDict")
                    self.productresponseArray = (responseDict["server_productresponse"] as AnyObject) as! NSArray
                    self.productDetailsArray = ((responseDict["server_productresponse"] as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "product_dtls") as AnyObject) as! NSArray
                    self.vehicleStatusStringArray = ((responseDict["server_productresponse"] as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "veh_status") as AnyObject) as! NSArray
                }

            })

        } else{
            let offlineResponseDict:NSDictionary = kUserDefault.value(forKey: "responseDict") as! NSDictionary
            print(offlineResponseDict as Any)
            self.productresponseArray = (offlineResponseDict["server_productresponse"] as AnyObject) as! NSArray
            self.productDetailsArray = ((offlineResponseDict["server_productresponse"] as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "product_dtls") as AnyObject) as! NSArray
            self.vehicleStatusStringArray = ((offlineResponseDict["server_productresponse"] as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "veh_status") as AnyObject) as! NSArray
        }
        // update UI on main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.homeTableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are variables set on the main thread? That is unnecessary and could be locking up your view, which may give the appearance that the userinteraction is disabled. Doing any thing on the main Thread that isn't related to UI, should be changed immediately. The only part of your code that should be on the main thread, is the reload function.